# Modeling small signal equivalent circuit of a transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, homework, small-signal

For this homework question, I have to model the circuit and find output impedance.  The question states that the capacitors can be modeled as short circuits.  As I think I understood it, the resistor R1 can be modeled as being in parallel to the other resistors and in parallel with R2, Re and Rl.  Is this an accurate simplified model of the transistor circuit?  If not, why?  By the way, the capital Ib and ib in the diagram are the same, I just realized I accidentally drew it with that inconsistency.[image]
[image]

Comment: where  is the capacitor in your schematic?

Comment: *R1 can be modeled as being in parallel to the other resistors and in parallel with R2, Re and Rl* Under the assumption that the capacitors are treated as a short then yes, this is correct. For simplicity, I would re-draw the small signal model and place **one** resistor between output and ground and give that resistor a value of: R = R1 || R2 || Re || Rl  (|| means in parallel).